# Filtering on a categorical binned variable pandas

Tags: python-3.x, binning

I have a data frame called `stroke_data_complete`, where we used binning on a variable using following code;

```
#Cut into 4 bins of equal frequency counts
stroke_data_complete['glucose_level_quartile'] = pd.qcut(stroke_data_complete['avg_glucose_level'], q=4)
stroke_data_complete['glucose_level_quartile'].value_counts();
```

When I check the datatypes for this new column;

```
stroke_data_complete['glucose_level_quartile'].dtypes
```

we get

```
CategoricalDtype(categories=[(55.119, 77.245], (77.245, 91.885], (91.885, 114.09], (114.09, 271.74]],
          ordered=True)
```

Next, I had to filter on one of the values of this new variable, here is my code for that;

```
stroke_data_complete.loc[stroke_data_complete.glucose_level_quartile==(114.09, 271.74]]
```

But I am getting following error;

```
SyntaxError: closing parenthesis ']' does not match opening parenthesis '(
```

And if I put quotes around it while filtering I am getting empty output. Can I kindly get some help in how to filter on this newly defined binned variable. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
stroke_data_complete['glucose_level_quartile'] = pd.qcut(stroke_data_complete['avg_glucose_level'], q=4, labels=False)
stroke_data_complete.loc[stroke_data_complete.glucose_level_quartile==3]
```

`labels=False` makes sure that the column contains the index of the quartile, not the values.

## Edit

Without `labels=False`, `qcut` returns a categorical `Series`. The underlying array is a `CategoricalArray`. The array is accessible through `Series.array` attribute, and its API is given [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/arrays.html#api-arrays-categorical)

In your example:

```
quartiles = pd.qcut(stroke_data_complete['avg_glucose_level'], q=4)
quartiles = quartiles.array
stroke_data_q_3 = stroke_data_complete.loc[quartiles.codes == 3]
avg_glucose_level_interval_q_3 = quartiles.categories[3]
```

Hope this helps

Comment: makes sense. thanks for feedback. so, as a followup is there a way to tie back the index and the actual bin intervals.If we want to know which index is representing which bin interval. kindly advice